# Why can't timeout take effect for tcpdump run under sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, tcpdump

I want to run the `tcpdump` command with a time limit of 10 seconds.

```
timeout 10 sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -nn 'host 192.168.1.176'
```

It doesn't stop. Why does the `timeout` command not take effect for `tcpdump` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `timeout` runs with your users privileges. The `sudo` process escalates privileges to root (or another user), so `timeout` is not allowed to send SIGTERM to the child process. This can be shown with `strace` (comments starting with `#` by me, as well as blank lines for readability):

```sh
user$ strace timeout 1 sudo sleep 5
# lots of irrelevant stuff
# here, timeout sets up the timer to get a signal when the child should be terminated
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], NULL, 8) = 0
timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, {sigev_value={sival_int=1889673072, sival_ptr=0x560c70a21f70}, sigev_signo=SIGALRM, sigev_notify=SIGEV_SIGNAL}, [0]) = 0
timer_settime(0, 0, {it_interval={tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, it_value={tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}}, NULL) = 0
wait4(12320, 0x7ffdfeb0ef0c, 0, NULL)   = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)

# the signal arrives
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_timerid=0, si_overrun=0, si_value={int=1889673072, ptr=0x560c70a21f70}} ---

# timeout tries to kill the child
kill(12320, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
# and gets EPERM!
```

The fix is to run timeout with root privileges also. The following will work as intended:

```sh
user$ sudo timeout 1 sleep 5
```

Of course, if you already *are* root, it doesn’t matter whether you put `timeout 1` before or after the `sudo` in the command line.

```sh
root$ sudo timeout 1 sleep 5
root$ timeout 1 sudo sleep 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
sudo timeout 10 tcpdump -i eth0 -nn 'host 192.168.1.176'
```